# What type of result to send to the client in Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Should I convert the list of Books from `IQueryable`, `IEnumarable` into Json (with NewtonJson), `ToList`, `ToArray`, ... before sending the result to the client ?

```
[HttpGet("")]
public IActionResult Index(int page=1)
{
    var books = context.Books.Skip((page-1) * 25).Take(25).ToList();
    
    return books;
}
```

Comment: In this particular scenario it is not needed. If you would separate your data access layer from your presentation layer then you should call one of the ToXYZ data materializer method inside the data access layer.

Comment: depends on your requirement. basically, for an web api, it may contain plenty of other messages except the main data, and the main data may set as the value of claim `data` in a Json object. E.g. `{"property1":"", "properity2":"", "data": books}`  but it all depends on your requirement. so no need for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model to return to you client like:

```
public class BooksModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

and return this like:

```
var books = context.Books.Skip((page - 1) * 25).Take(25).ToList();

var model = books.Select(x => new BooksModel()
{
    BookId = x.BookId, // depends on what you want to return
    BookName = x.BookName, // depends on what you want to return
}).ToList();

return model;
```

Comment: Mmmm yes, thank you :), yes of course I've just remembered that I have/must to return only the piece of that data, thank you DANIEL !!!!

Comment: How does this post answer OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to convert your result from list to the format which should be send to client. one way is, you can convert your result to JSON format.

For that you can use the method json() from Newtonsoft.Json library which would return the result in the json string.

Example:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public IActionResult Index(int page=1)
{
    var books = context.Books.Skip((page-1) * 25).Take(25).ToList();
    
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(books);

    return Json(json);
}
```

The following, returns your result in json string, which can be sent to client.